# How do I evaluate this definite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

Given a function $y=f(x)$ satisfying $xf(x^2)+3f(x)=3x^5+9x^2+x+3$ with domain $\mathbb{R}$, evaluate $\int_{-1}^0 f(x).$
The method I have tried is to integrate both side:
$$\int_{-1}^0xf(x^2)dx+3\int_{-1}^0f(x)dx=\int_{-1}^0(3x^5+9x^2+x+3)dx$$
With the integrand $\int_{-1}^0xf(x^2)dx$, I substituted: $u=x^2→du=2xdx→xdx=\dfrac{du}{2}$
Which gave me: $$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{1}^0f(u)du$$ therefore: $$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{1}^0f(x)dx$$
I was struggling because the lower bound is $1$ and what I wanted is $-1$, did I make any mistakes? And are there any better way to solve this?

Comment: Show that $f(x)=3x^2+1$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: That is surely the only *polynomial* solution of the question. How would you argue that there are no other solutions? It is not obvious to me, perhaps I am overlooking something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that $\int_{-1}^0xf(x^2) \, dx$ is equal to $\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^0f(x)\,dx$, and that is equal to $-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^1f(x)\, dx$.

So the integration from $-1$ to $0$ gives the value of
$$
\int_{-1}^0xf(x^2)\,dx+3\int_{-1}^0f(x)\,dx = -\frac 12 \int_0^1 f(x)\, dx + 3\int_{-1}^0f(x)\,dx \, .
$$
Now integrate the equation from $0$ to $1$, that gives the value of
$$
\int_{0}^1xf(x^2)\,dx+3\int_{0}^1f(x)\,dx = \frac 12 \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx + 3\int_{0}^1f(x)\,dx \, .
$$
Using both results you can now compute $\int_{-1}^0 f(x) \,dx$.

Comment: What I want to compute is $\int_{-1}^0f(x)dx$, not $\int_0^1f(x)dx$, I wonder if they got any relationship?

Comment: @Snek: There was a typo in the last line which is now fixed.  Note that you can compute *both* quantities from the two equations.

Comment: Excuse me, can you please explain a bit further on how to compute $\int_{-1}^0f(x)dx$ based on the given values? Thank you!

Comment: @Snek: From the second equation you get the value of $\int_0^1f(x)dx$. Substitute that in the first equation to compute $\int_{-1}^0f(x)dx$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As commented you can first find $f(x)$:

suppose $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ we have:

$xf(x^2)+3f(x)=ax^5+bx^3+3ax^2+(3b+c)x+3c=3x^5+9x^2+x+3$

which gives $(a, b, c)=(3, 0, 1)$

So $f(x)=3x^2+1$ which is easy to integrate.

Comment: Why can you assume that $f$ is a polynomial? That is not given in the question, as far as I can see.

Comment: How can not f(x) be not a polynomial when $xf(x^2)+3f(x)$ is a polynomial. Can you give an example?

Comment: $f(x) = 3x^2 +1 + g(x)$ is a solution if $x g(x^2) + 3g(x) = 0$, and I am fairly sure that the latter equation has non-trivial solutions, although it might be difficult to write them down explicitly. It *may* be that $f(x) = 3x^2+1$ is the only continuous (bounded, integrable, ...) solution, but in any case, it requires some justification.

Comment: @MartinR, I learned something new, thank you.